# PHP, PHTML and other files get directories after updating via ./mage update-all

Tags: magento-1.9, php, phtml

Since Magento 1.9.2.x (don't know which version exactly, but seems to be since 1.9.2.2) when updating via `./mage update-all` some files turn into directories.

This belongs to default files like `./app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Type/Configurable/Product/Collection.php` or `./app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/xmlconnect/edit/tab/design/preview/tab_items_android.phtml`

I haven't figured out if there is a kind of pattern to make this happen. Also i'm wondering, if nobody else has made this experience till now?

Is this a known issue or is there even a workaround to prevent this behaviour? The only way to get my backend working is to delete the 'folders' and upload the files from e.g. a Magento 1.9.2.3 archive (or whatever version i need).

Comment: I'd be interested to see what's the cause of this. I've faced the same issue yesterday. Ended up deleting the affected files/folders (how do we call them in that case ? ^^) and use the install --force to fix the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Long file names and Magento Connect extension packager](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5585/long-file-names-and-magento-connect-extension-packager)

Comment: @mam08ixo Thanks for the link. I will check this in another setup, i've to update in some hours or tomorrow. If it is the solution, i'll give feedback and answer myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've done a test with another installation. The link given by @mam08ixo worked nearly correct.

I still received some "directory-files" like

```
./app/design/frontend/default/iphone/locale/de_DE/translate.csv
./app/design/frontend/default/modern/locale/de_DE/translate.csv
./app/design/frontend/default/blank/locale/de_DE/translate.csv
```

So i don't know if i should mark the given link as "solved my problem" as it is one thing, but not a real solution. Seems all things, that getting updated right after the Downloader will get screwed. And the given links aren't 100+ chars.

Perhaps someone has an extended solution?

EDIT: 
And another "candidate" is back again, with a short directory, that is against the given link and 100+ char Links:
`./pkginfo/Mage_All_Latest.txt`

It will lead into problems upgrading to a new version, so you have to delete this file before doing an upgrade with ./mage or via Magento CM.