# Unable to update via Connect Manager since 1.9.2.3

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, magento-connect

Never had any issues using Magento Connect Manager until I tried to go from 1.9.2.2 to 1.9.2.3 or the latest 1.9.2.4. It will not update anything connected with Magento

I get the same errors see log [here](http://pastebin.com/xDZTbV9L)

I have done the patches via SSH no issue and my other extensions install correctly. But Mage will not install.

Any ideas, please
Thorrrr

Comment: upvoting the question as 1.9.3 will bring the same issue to new people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will check for pkginfo/Mage_All_Latest.txt, you will see it's a directory. Just delete it.

See [PHP, PHTML and other files get directories after updating via ./mage update-all](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101243/php-phtml-and-other-files-get-directories-after-updating-via-mage-update-all)

Comment: Top man thank you so much fixed it in a jiffy. Not sure how to mark it fixed

Comment: this is still the solution as of the current 1.9.3 update

Comment: in deed it is. Still don't get the point, why Magento isn't trying to get around this 'bug'. Maybe they say, it's related to tar not to them.